# Simplifying/Approximating Hypergeometric Function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I have been working with Closed-form Hypergeometric function. Is there any possibility to simplify this function with multiple variables? Even if the approximation would be great.

> `Hypergeometric2F1[1,2/x,1+2/x,a^x]`

Comment: It depends on what you know about `a` and `x`.  If `x` is a positive integer and you apply `FunctionExpand`, then you can get a great deal of simplification.  For example, `Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2/x, 1 + 2/x, a^x] /. x -> 8 // FunctionExpand` results in `ArcTan[a^2]/(2 a^2) + ArcTanh[a^2]/(2 a^2)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if both `a` and `x` are unknowns? Would it be possible to simplify it in closed-form equations? I have already tried `FunctionExpand` it seems only one variable workings.

Comment: Do you know something about the range of values for `a` and `x` ? Do you have `0 < a <1`?  And when `x` is an integer you do get a result that is a function of `a` so it "works" to give you a simplification without having to set a value of `a`.  And I would call what I gave a "hint" as opposed to an "answer".

Comment: Hi JimB. Thank you for your answers. I appreciated.

The thing ia x is not integer. It could be decimal/fractions. I would say I know the range of `x`; however, I do have to get `x` in a function of `a` right? I cannot directly simplify these equation in both 2 unknown variables?

Comment: But if `x` is rational, then simplification can still occur: `Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2/x, 1 + 2/x, a^x] /. x -> 5/3 // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify`.  If `x` is real, then there's likely no simplification.